# Как сэкономить память на шрифтах в AndEngine?

Tags: android, шрифты, andengine

Я использую левый шрифт в приложении на `AndEngine`.

Словил себя на мысли, что в каждом `Activity` я заново создаю `TextureBitmap` для шрифта, и, собственно, загружаю шрифт. Учитывая, что размер шрифта составляет от 100 до 200 для разных `Activity`, есть подозрение, что это нехило ест память, что для нетоповых девайсов может быть критично.

Как правильно пользоваться шрифтами в AndEngine?

**Пример загрузки шрифта:**

```
ITexture fontTexture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(
    getTextureManager(),
    1024,
    1024,
    TextureOptions.BILINEAR
);
Font font = FontFactory.createFromAsset(
    fontTexture,
    this,
    "Droid.ttf",
    FONT_SIZE,
    true,
    Color.BLACK
);
font.load();
```

Comment: Мне кажется, нужно создать TextureBitmap в конструкторе класса, или нет?

Comment: Какого класса? У меня, например, 6 разных активити - это 6 разных классов.

Comment: Ну допустим, 7 класса TextureBitmapСl, например, и разделить его между 6-ю остальными?

Comment: Создай синглтон и объяви в нем TextureBitmap, Font и используй сколько душе угодно)